# Bootstrap 4 Modal with JavaScript and Vue: $ is not defined at eval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm simply trying to launch a Bootstrap 4 modal from my Javascript code in my Vue 3 app. Every time the execution reaches the modal launch line however, I get this error: `$ is not defined at eval`

The other common questions about this seem to reference not including jQuery into the project more than once, i'm not sure if that's the issue causing the problem i'm seeing.

Code below, what am I doing incorrectly to launch the Bootstrap modal?

**Html**

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div
    class="modal fade"
    id="errorModal"
    tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
    aria-hidden="true"
  >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">
            {{ modalTitle }}}
          </h5>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal"
            aria-label="Close"
          >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{ modalMessage }}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    doNetworkedThings(requestHeader, profile) {
      let that = this;
      axios
        .post(
          "http://localhost:8080/endpoint",
          profile,
          requestHeader
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("Success");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          //show error modal
          $('#errorModal').modal({  //TODO: fails on this line
            keyboard: false,
            backdrop: "static"
          })
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What is `$('#errorModal')` supposed to mean? Because it looks like you're expecting a jQuery selector to work when you haven't loaded jQuery in your page.

Comment: @tao $('#errorModal').modal() is the syntax from the modal docs on bootstraps website: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Bootstrap has a JS part. `bootstrap.min.js`. By default (standalone), it is dependent on jQuery. BootstrapVue is a rewrite of that bit directly using Vue components and directives and you no longer need jQuery. So all of the jQuery syntax/examples in Bootstrap's documentation don't work in BootstrapVue. You have to use the BV syntax. The Vue way.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

its works for me

Comment: A better solution would be to use BootstrapVue rather than load jQuery, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, if you will

Comment: @tao I'm already using BootstrapVue but the modal still isn't working as described in the Bootstrap docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). Do I have to use jQuery? The docs aren't clear on this being a requirement.

Comment: Ah, i just realized since i'm using BootstrapVue I need to be following the BootstrapVue docs for modal. My mistake! (https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. You don't need the jQuery syntax. BV replaces everything jQuery in Bootstrap, so that syntax doesn't work. You want to place a `v-b-modal="'errorModal'"` directive on some button or you can open it programmatically using `this.$bvModal.show('errorModal')`. @Cody However, you might have a slight problem. I'm not entirely sure BootstrapVue is Vue 3 ready yet.

Comment: Sure enough; the Bootstrap team is working to release BootstrapVue v4 to support Vue 3. They initially planned to have it ready by the end of 2020, so it looks like we should be getting an official release "soon" https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196